# Error: Instagram: Redirect URI does not match registered URI

Tags: swift, oauth-2.0, instagram

Wow, one of the harder challenges, working on this for a few days now. There are a 1/2 dozen solutions, yet still getting this error. Swift 1.2, Xcode 6.3. And my Redirect absolutely matches my registered URI. Help most appreciated.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

```
oauth-swift://oauth-callback/instagram
```

Comment: That gets us one step further. But once you click `authorize` safari says that the address can not be reached

Comment: This seems to do it:   ig[client_id]://oauth-swift/instagram. Register that with Instagram, and you should be good to go.  URL Types: Identifier is your bundle ID (reverse domain + App name). And URL Schemes is just your ig[client_id] and nothing else. No :, //, etc. It a few pieces for sure, but once setup, does work.

Comment: Edward, i have settee everything like you said and it still dosent work, i mean i can login but after i press the "authorize" its pops up  the uri error, What do you think? :)